# SQL Loader to split a string base on certain requirements into a new field

Tags: sql, sql-loader

I have a flat file that contains a list of people's name.
I need to split the last name into a new column when executing sql loader.

Here's the tricky part.
I need to split out the surename if it's uppercase base on the following scenarios.

| Original Name | Surename split |
| --- | --- |
| THOMAS Young | THOMAS |
| SMITH Lucas (A.K.A Luca SMITH) | SMITH |
| Dan bin Islam bin Al-BALUSHI | BALUSHI |
| James GORDON-LOPEZ | GORDON-LOPEZ |

Comment: Just to clarify, the logic here is: Split out any word if that word is all uppercase?

Comment: @JNevill not any word. If the words are together and they happen to be all UPPER case, then they should be split out. If there are multiple UPPER case words that are separated by lower case word(s) then only return the first one as seen in example SMITH Lucas (A.K.A Luca SMITH)